# Input data for infernce in SageMaker autoML fas.AI model

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, fast-ai

I've run a SageMaker AutoPilot job to create a fast.AI model for me. Now I'm trying to run inference over this model but I'm having some problems. Every time I run the predict model I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-f494677f3a22> in <module>
----> 1 pred = predictor.predict(sample)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id)
    159             data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id
    160         )
--> 161         response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    162         return self._handle_response(response)
    163 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528                 )
    529             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 530             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    531 
    532         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    958             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    959             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 960             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    961         else:
    962             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from primary with message "list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker_inference/transformer.py", line 128, in transform
    result = self._transform_fn(self._model, input_data, content_type, accept)
  File "/opt/ml/model/code/tabular_serve.py", line 58, in transform_fn
    request_body = request_body[DATA][FEATURES][VALUES]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
". See https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-west-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/mappia-automl-fastai-endpoint-endpoint in account XXXXXXX for more information.
```

My input data for the predcit method is a numpy array of shape 10000x19 whith dtype=float32 and no NaN values. This is the code I use to run the model and to get this error, I tried both serializers (numpy and json), but numpy was giving erro that the content_type is not supported.

```
from sagemaker.serializers import BaseSerializer, NumpySerializer, JSONSerializer
from sagemaker.deserializers import NumpyDeserializer
np_serializer = NumpySerializer()
np_deserializer = NumpyDeserializer()
json_serializer = JSONSerializer()
inf_data = json_serializer.serialize(sample)


from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor
predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=sess, serializer=json_serializer, deserializer=np_deserializer)
pred = predictor.predict(sample)
```

I already created the model endpoint using the following code:

```
sm_client = boto3.client('sagemaker', region_name='us-west-2')
job_name = 'mappia-automl-fastia'

describe_response = sm_client.describe_auto_ml_job(AutoMLJobName=job_name)
# extract the best candidate definition from DescribeAutoMLJob response
best_candidate = describe_response['BestCandidate']
# extract the InferenceContainers definition from the caandidate definition
inference_containers = best_candidate['InferenceContainers']


# Create Model
model_name = 'mappia-automl-fastai-model' 
sagemaker_role = role
create_model_response = sm_client.create_model(
   ModelName = model_name,
   ExecutionRoleArn = sagemaker_role,
   Containers = inference_containers 
)       

endpoint_config_name = 'mappia-automl-fastai-endpoint-config'
                                                        
instance_type = 'ml.g4dn.12xlarge' 
# for all supported instance types, see 
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ProductionVariant.html#sagemaker-Type-ProductionVariant-InstanceType    # Create endpoint config

endpoint_config_response = sm_client.create_endpoint_config(
   EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name, 
   ProductionVariants=[
       {
           "VariantName": "variant1",
           "ModelName": model_name, 
           "InstanceType": instance_type,
           "InitialInstanceCount": 1
       }
   ]
)

print(f"Created EndpointConfig: {endpoint_config_response['EndpointConfigArn']}")                

# create endpoint and deploy the model
create_endpoint_response = sm_client.create_endpoint(
                                            EndpointName=endpoint_name, 
                                            EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name)

print(create_endpoint_response)
```